# How to use a button in bottle?

Tags: python, html, css, button, bottle

I am making a simple currency exchanger with [Bottle](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/).

I want to make a submit button so that when I click it, some text will be triggered on the page I am on.

So far I only know how to make a new template so that the button takes me to a new page, but I don't know how to add it to the page I am on.

```
import bottle


def exchanger():
    amount = float(bottle.request.forms["amount"])
    currency1 = bottle.request.forms["currency1"]
    valuta2 = bottle.request.forms["currency2"]
    return bottle.template("result.html", 
             calculate=calculate,
             amount=amount, 
             currency1=currency1, 
             currency2=currency2)
```

Comment: You should either use a form, or an event trigger on the button click that calls an API route in your application.

Comment: Bottle is a server-side framework, so it cannot update a page without reloading. One option would be use AJAX and JQuery when the button is clicked to send a post request to a Bottle route you specify that will return the result data (possibly as JSON) to a JavaScript function that would update the part of the page you want.